# Datepicker - change format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to read the date from one input box and use that to populate the datepicker field. The input format is yy-mm-dd and I want to read the datepicker field in the same format.

The code I am using is populating the correct date in datepicker but it is in mm/dd/yy format whereas I want the datepicker field to be in the yy-mm-dd format

My code is given below. Where am I going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id2").datepicker();
  $("#id2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
});

$("#btn").click(function() {
  var x = $("#id1").val();
  alert(x);
  var z = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', x);
  alert(z);

  $("#id2").datepicker("setDate", z);
  var y = $("#id2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  }).val();
  alert(y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="id1" type="text" />
  <input id="btn" type="submit" />
  <input id="id2" type="text" readonly/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi its very simple you do not need to initialize date picker in default format.
see below code. I just rearranged your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
});

$("#btn").click(function() {
  var x = $("#id1").val();
  $("#id2").datepicker("setDate", x);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="id1" type="text" />
  <input id="btn" type="submit" />
  <input id="id2" type="text" readonly/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing the datepicker twice, remove the first and keep the second one with the date format option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // cahce element reference for later use
  let $id2 = $("#id2"),
    $id1 = $("#id1");

  $id2.datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' // set dateformat here
  });

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    // get input value
    var x = $id1.val();
    // parse the date string to get date object using datepicker utility function
    var z = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', x);
    // update the date by using setDate method
    $id2.datepicker("setDate", z);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div>
  <input id="id1" value="2019-03-13" type="text" />
  <input id="btn" type="submit" />
  <input id="id2" type="text" readonly/>
</div>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: No... getDate again gives the result in mm/dd/yy format only.

Comment: @coderatlarge :  why you want to get it in that format ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan just for information first textbox is not datepicker according to user need its a free form text

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first datepicker instantiation: `$("#id2").datepicker();`.

It seems like you tried to instantiate it first, then set an option...
It would have been like this instead:

```
$("#id2").datepicker();
$("#id2").datepicker("option", {
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#options) about changing an option once instantiated.

But it ok to instantiate with options all at once like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
});

$("#btn").click(function() {
  var x = $("#id1").val();
  alert(x);
  var z = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', x);
  alert(z);

  $("#id2").datepicker("setDate", z);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="id1" type="text" />
  <input id="btn" type="submit" />
  <input id="id2" type="text" readonly/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<DatePicker className="form-control" name="startDate"
                                            selected={this.state.startDate} 
                                            autoComplete="off"
                                            selectStart
                                            startDate={this.state.startDate}
                                            endDate={this.state.endDate}
                                            onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
                                            dateFormat="dd-MM-YYYY"
                                            onChange={(e) => {
                                                $(".requiredfield").hide()
                                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                                    var endDate = new Date();
                                                })
                                                this.setState({
                                                    isSelect: true,
                                                    startDate: moment(e).format("YYYY-MM-DD") == "Invalid date" ? null : moment(e).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                                                })
                                            }}
                                            required />
                                        <i className="fa fa-calendar"></i>
```